# Check for a value zero in a column using python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file and I am using Pandas to find a column value which has value '0' and then if it is '0' I would like to have new column which has a value of specific columns, if not I would  like to add a values of two column to this new column. 
I am trying to do as below and it is not yielding the results.
a['testcol'] = np.where((a['SLOT'].nonzero()[0]),a['name'] + '_' + a['SLOT'],a['name'])
I end up always getting the concatenated values in the new column whether the column has value '0' or any other integer value.
Please help. 
My dataframe is having two columns (Name, Slot). I want to create an additional column called testcol having values as below: 
1) If Slot has any other values other than '0' testcol = Name+Slot 
2) If Slot has value '0' testcol = Name

Comment: please post a sample df and expected df\

Comment: My dataframe is having two columns (Name, Slot). I want to create an additional column called testcol having values as below:                                                                         1) If Slot has any other values other than '0' testcol = Name+Slot                              2) If Slot has value '0' testcol = Name

Answer (score 0):

I got this resolved myself. I was using a function to check for nonzero values.
Here I just did a compare of string directly.
Thanks for the help.
a['testcol'] = np.where(a['SLOT'] == '0',a['name'],a['name'] + '_' + a['SLOT'])